# Mac OS X Lion can't install SDK and xCode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sdk

I would like to begin coding for iPhone and iPad so I installed `Mac OS X Lion` on `VMWare`. I  tried to install `xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final (3.5)GB` from the Apple developer website, but I can't install it because an error message appears saying `"error on installation, contact your adminstrator"`

I then downloaded `xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final (4.1)GB`, but when I launch it I receive an error message stating `"the following disk image couldn't be opened"`.

I am so new to Mac OS X, what am I doing wrong?

1. is there SDK for Lion and SDK for another version of Mac OS X?
2. are there special configuration considerations for VMWare?
3. how do I know which version of iOS I have?

I know this is a silly question, but I could really use the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple versions of Xcode for each of the Mac OS X operating systems.

Xcode 3.2.5 is for an older version of Mac OS X and will *not* run on Mac OS X Lion. You will need to download Xcode version 4 or later to install on Mac OS X Lion.

If you are installing the latest version of Xcode, it is now a universal binary for both Lion and Mountain Lion.

If instead you are trying to install an older version the installer will say something to the effect of "Xcode 4.x.x for Lion".

Xcode is also now available on the Mac App Store for free: click the Apple menu then click "App Store..." and then search for Xcode to install it.

Comment: when i tried to install xcode 4.5  i got this message `you can't use this version of the application xcode with this version of max os x .
you have max os x 10.7.2 , the application requires mac os x 10.7.4 or later`

Comment: You need to install Mac OS X system software updates. Click the Apple menu in the upper left corner of the desktop then click "Software Update..." to install the updates you need to make the installer work.

Comment: ok i will update the max os, but then have i need to install SDK ?

Comment: Yes, you need to install Xcode (which includes the latest SDK) after installing the system updates to Ma**c** OS X.

Comment: really thank you for helping, tomorrow i will update the mac os , i accepted your answer :)

Comment: Glad to help! Hopefully this will resolve your issues and you can be developing Apps soon!

Comment: now i update my mac and i had this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157668/mac-os-x-lion-cant-log-in-after-updating-in-vmware would you please help me

Comment: Hah, I have to laugh at this *problem->update fixes all->new problem* timeline :) Apple have their sh_t together. Those with experience know how badly devs are treated, the others (non-intersecting set) keep recommending updates as the cure-all.

Answer (score 1):

You should download it there: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/. (at least 4.3.2 for lion. latest is 4.5.1)

By the way xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final are old version of Xcode, so it's normal you can't run it on Lion

Comment: i already download it from that site

Comment: i also download xcode 4.5 but without sdk, can i run it alone?

Comment: Yes, you are able to run it alone without sdk, as i remember sdk will automatically install

Comment: i will try it, just some mins please

Comment: Yeah you can download Xcode alone, but xcode is a sdk, and ios4.2 is actually the simulator (+ documentation). We're now in iOS version 6, and Xcode 4.5.2. That's why your .dmg is obsolete. You can download Xcode, and it will automatically asking you to download latest iOS simulator + documentation.

Comment: when i tried to install xcode 4.5  i got this message `you can't use this version of the application xcode with this version of max os x .
you have max os x 10.7.2 , the application requires mac os x 10.7.4 or later`

Comment: Yeah, you need MacOs 10.7.4 in order to run Xcode Xcode 4.5.2, but you can instal Xcode 4.3.2 on macos x 10.7.2, don't forget you will not be able to compile for IOS6 with this version. Or do an macios update with wmware if you can.